# The above error occurred in the <Connect(App)> component:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and all of its components and stuff, and im following a youtube video where the code is like this. I get an error with the "checked: session.checked" line where checked is undefined. I have no idea how to fix this and ive been searching all over the web trying to find an answer. Do any of you know what the problem is?

```
//pages
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import './scss/base.css';
import { StyledContainer } from './components/Styles'

import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";

import AuthRoute from './components/AuthRoute.js';
import BasicRoute from './components/BasicRoute.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function App({ checked }) {
  return (
    <Router>
      {checked && (
        <StyledContainer>
          <Routes>
            <AuthRoute exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <AuthRoute exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <BasicRoute exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <BasicRoute exact path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          </Routes>
        </StyledContainer>
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ session }) => ({
  checked: session.checked
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

The video im following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCnHYz6TXA4&list=PLk8gdrb2DmChrL50moKeFNAVnFqZ3GLF7&index=6, and its 1h and 52m in when i get the issue

Comment: Seems like issue in destructing

Comment: can you share  what video you follow ?

Comment: The video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCnHYz6TXA4&list=PLk8gdrb2DmChrL50moKeFNAVnFqZ3GLF7&index=6, and its 1h and 52minutes in

Comment: Do you have <Provider> in the parent component? If you can create a page on codesanbox with minimal sourcecode - I'm happy to dive into the issue

Comment: That would be great! I put the code in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-shape-zos70?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark